# How do I use Semantic UI with React and Express?

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm new to Semantic/React/Express. How do I include the stylesheet for Semantic in React? Do I need an html file that directly links to the Semantic css/JavaScript files? Right now, I'm not using any html files.

My main page, `dashboard.jsx`:

```
var React = require('react');
var Layout = require('./layout');

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout title={this.props.title}>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <div class="ui three item menu">
          <a class="active item">Editorials</a>
          <a class="item">Reviews</a>
          <a class="item">Upcoming Events</a>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  title: React.PropTypes.string
};

module.exports = Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `className` instead of `class` in your React components.

And to use the classes just import the css file normally in your html file. React only renders your code as HTML in the end, if your `.css` file exists in the imports normally the classes will be applied.

To import CSS just add to your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_css_here.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the package with npm and build with gulp:

`npm install semantic-ui --save`

`cd semantic/`

`gulp build`

You can then import the `min.css` file into your `dashboard.js`:

`import '../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'`

Remember to use the `className` identifier rather than `class` in your JSX. From the React docs:

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components expect DOM property names like className and htmlFor, respectively.